# Linked List Insertion in C

Tags: c, list, shell, unix, pointers

I want to write a program which takes last prompted inputs from the user and prints them in order.
Here is the code snippet that i have problem about :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <termios.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#define MAXCHARNUM 128
#define MAXARGNUM 32

char *argsexec[MAXARGNUM];
char str[500];
char *path;
char *name;
int length;
int sizeOfHistory=0;

struct History{
    char *hname;
    struct History *nextPtr;
    struct History *prevPtr;
}*nextPtr=NULL,*prevPtr=NULL;


struct History *Head = NULL;
struct History *Tail = NULL;
struct History *Temp = NULL;
struct History *Temp2 = NULL;
struct History *historyTemp = NULL;

void HistoryList(char *historyName){

    struct History *historyTemp = (struct History *)malloc(sizeof(struct History));

    if(sizeOfHistory == 0)
    {
        historyTemp->hname=historyName;
        historyTemp->prevPtr = NULL;
        historyTemp->nextPtr = NULL;
        Tail = historyTemp;
        Head = historyTemp;
        sizeOfHistory++;
        printf("Histtemp's :%s ",historyTemp->hname);
        printf("Head's name: %s ",Head->hname);
        printf("Tail's name: %s ",Tail->hname);
    }



    else if (sizeOfHistory < 10){

        historyTemp->hname=historyName;
        historyTemp->prevPtr = NULL;
        historyTemp->nextPtr = NULL;


        Head->prevPtr = historyTemp;
        historyTemp->nextPtr = Head;
        Head = historyTemp;
        sizeOfHistory++;
        printf("Head's name: %s ",Head->hname);

    }

    else{
        historyTemp->hname=historyName;
        Head->prevPtr = historyTemp;
        historyTemp->nextPtr = Head;
        Head = historyTemp;
        Tail=Tail->prevPtr;
        Temp=Tail->nextPtr;
        Tail->nextPtr = NULL;
        Temp->prevPtr = NULL;
        free(Temp);
    }
    //historyTemp=NULL;
}

void printHistory(){

    int counter=1;
    struct History *historyT=NULL;
    historyT = Head;

    while(historyT != NULL){
        printf("[%d] [%s] \n",counter,historyT->hname);
        historyT=historyT->nextPtr;
        counter++;
    }
}


void Setup(){

    while(1){


        while (!feof(stdin))
        {
            fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
            HistoryList(str);
        }

    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Setup();
    return 0;
}
```

Normally after program gets second input from the user it should only change the historyTemp's hname.

But it changes Head and Tail's as well.How can i change it ? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't allocating any memory to historyName

Instead of

```
historyTemp->hname=historyName;
```

do

```
historyTemp->hname=strdup(historyName);
```

You assign the Head->previous in at least one place.  Makes no sense.

Can't quite make out your logic for insertion?

Here's what I would do

Assuming insertion at Tail

I would make a temp

if it is the first insert, set the head to temp

set Tail->next to temp
set the temp->previous to Tail
set the temp->next to NULL

Hope this helps